# Generic function to check if value exists within DbSet

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core

If I have multiple dbSets within my dbContext, for example:

- public DbSet Persons { get; set; }
- public DbSet Companies { get; set; }
- public DbSet<...>

How could I than create a generic function to check if the value of a dynamically passed field already occurs?

Function in pseudo code:

```
bool IsFieldValueUnique<T>(field, fieldValue)
{
  return DbSet<T>.Any(x => x.field == fieldValue)
}
```

And function calls could then be something like:

```
var result1 = IsFieldValueUnique<Person>(Person.Email, somePersonObject.Email)

var result2 = IsFieldValueUnique<Company>(Company.Identification, someCompanyObject.Identification)
```

When searching around, I find approaches like using '<Func<T, bool>>', but can't connect the dots together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Func<T, bool>` - Sounds like the right approach to what you want.

```
bool IsFieldValueUnique<T>(Func<T, bool> checkFunction)
{
  var alreadyExists = DbSet<T>.Any(checkFunction);
  return !alreadyExists;
  //Other ways to do this, but this is just for clarity.
}
```

Then you call it like:

```
IsFieldValueUnique<Person>(person => person.Email == somePersonObject.Email)
```

What you have now is a method `IsFieldValueUnique` that takes a check function.
This check function takes in a `T` (of the same type as you use in the DbSet) and returns a boolean value.

`person => person.Email == somePersonObject.Email` is an anonymous function that for a given instance of a `Person` compare the `Email` property with `somePersonObject.Email`.

If you look at the signature for Any you will see similarities with the checkFunction signature.

If you want to try it on Customer you can:

```
IsFieldValueUnique<Customer>(cust => person.Name == someCustomer.Name);
```

Note:

Calling Any like this: `DbSet<T>.Any(checkFunction);`

Is the same as this: `DbSet<T>.Any(item => checkFunction(item));`

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsFieldValueUnique<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
  return DbSet<T>.AsQueryable().Any(predicate.Compile());
}

And use it like this:

bool unique = IsFieldValueUnique<Person>(p => p.Email == something.Email);
```

Comment: Why `Compile`? It is correct answer but Compile is not needed.

Comment: Because the Func it's wrapped with Expression<>

Comment: Try to do do that without `Compile`. I think in this case you will not load whole table into the memory.